# TcpListener TcpClient get IPAddress

Tags: c#, tcp

I wish to get the **IPAddress** from

Server side

```
TcpListener ftp_listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, ftpport);
 newclient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

how do I find **newclient** ipaddress please

client side

```
TcpClient ftpclient = new TcpClient();
 ftpclient.Connect(ipAddress, ftpport);
```

how do I find **ftpclient** ipaddress

Currently I am using

```
 TcpClient ftpclient = new TcpClient();

            //get IpAddress of Server
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.Resolve("localhost").AddressList[0];
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete

            ftpclient.Connect(ipAddress, ftpport);// "192.168.1.160", ftpport);
```

Is there a better way ...

Thanks

Comment: So you have Server and Client on the same machine. Usually, the user needs to provide the client with the address (or host) to connect to. So, I am having difficulties to see, where you are going with this. You could iterate your NetworkAdapters, but what's the point?

Comment: use `newClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()`. the `newClient.Client` gives you the underlying socket.

Comment: Am testing on the same pc ... I need a way of finding the ipaddress of each pc clients

Comment: @Fildor, he might be writing an ftp client, and the PASV/PORT commands means that one party to the conversation needs to tell the other what IP/port to use

Comment: @CaiusJard Ah, right. That makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For both server and client, the approach for getting the remote endpoint (IP Address and Port) is the same.

1. Get the client IP Address on the server:

   ```
   IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = newclient.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
   Console.WriteLine("Client IP Address is: {0}", remoteIpEndPoint.Address);
   ```
2. Get the server IP Address on the client:

   ```
       IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = ftpclient.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
       Console.WriteLine("FTP Server IP Address is: {0}", remoteIpEndPoint.Address);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First your server code is wrong, you cannot accept client before starting the server so the code need to be like this

```
TcpListener ftp_listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, ftpport);
ftp_listener.Start();
var newclient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

// getting the client ip 2 ways :
var clientIpLAN = newclient.Client.LocalEndPoint; // locally this return "127.0.0.1:[YourServerFTPPort]"
var clientIpWAN = newclient.Client.RemoteEndPoint; // locally this return "127.0.0.1:[totally random port]"
```

For the client to get the server IP that is not possible to find by magic. You need to know where you want to connect. There are many ways but all need 1 static location you know is always available. A web service for example could give you a list (or a single one) of IP that are valid to connect to right now. You might have a web database that has the IP you can connect to. If you are ALWAYS having the server and client running on the same computer then `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` is almost always working given that there is no host file shenanigan.

Comment: Should not it be RemoteEndPoint?

Comment: @OguzOzgul you are right i should mention. It will depend on what he need. Remote will return the WAN and Local the LAN

Comment: No, LocalEndPoint will return the ip address and port to which the tcp connection is accepted. We are listening on a specific port, but when we accept a tcp connection, it is accepted on a different, free port. RemoteEndPoint will give the destination (remote) IP Address and Port.